# Can squid block an access to the specific IP-address which is resolved with a domain name?

Tags: proxy, squid, pac

I have a `.pac` file like below.

```
if (dnsDomainIs(host, ".example.com")) {
    hostip = dnsResolve(host);
    if (isInNet(hostip, "202.0.0.0", "255.255.255.0")) {
        return "DIRECT";
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to convert this into `squid.conf`.

A client wants to access to `example.com` **whose IP address would be changed everyday**. If the **destination IP is in the range** `202.0.0.0/24`, I need to change the proxy routing(Direct, proxy-A, proxy-B and so on).

I know how to change the proxies with `squid.conf` but I don't know how to define the access which would access into the IP range **from just a domain name**. I think squid knows only the destination domain name.

If the client accesses with IP, I can distinguish it. Though if the client accesses with a domain name, I can't.

Does anybody know a squid option for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting up combined ACLs that only trigger on a match on dstdomain and dst.

```
acl addom dstdomain example.com
acl addst dst 202.0.0.0/24
always_direct allow addst addom
```

Comment: That's perfect for me. I appreciate you so much!